# ember route params lost after this.refresh()

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my route, I refresh the page after I update the date, but after refreshing, the params in the url lost.

The url before is like: `http://localhost:4200/#/ss/xxx?id=1`

The url after is like: `http://localhost:4200/#/ss/xxx`

The param is important because I need it in my server.

The front script is as follow:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    loginInfo: Ember.inject.service(),
    model: function() {
        return this.store.query('my-stablity-project', {
            creator: this.get('loginInfo').get('staffId'),
            bizId:this.getQueryString("bizId")
        });
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);
        controller.set('my-project', model);
        let array = model.toArray();
        var str = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            str += array[i].get('keludeId') + ',';
        }
        this.store.query('kelude-result', {
            keludeIds: str
        }).then(results => {
            controller.set('kelude-result', results);
        });
        this.store.query('kelude-week-result', {
            keludeIds: str
        }).then(results => {
            controller.set('kelude-week-result', results);
        });
    },
    actions: {
        findProjects: function(projectId) {
            this.store.query('kelude-project', {
                projectId: projectId
            });
        },
        updateMySub: function() {
            this.refresh();
        }
    }
});
```

This situation happens when the action `updateMySub` is executed.

Comment: where are you defining your query params? i don't see any defined on this route and you haven't posted your controller

Comment: Using query params with this.refresh() should not unset your query params. Here's an ember twiddle that shows a scaled down version of the problem: https://ember-twiddle.com/91b9ee17dc23579ff7c0379a4e5edc78

You can see the model() hook is called via the refresh in the route. I also track the refreshes to show that the app isn't being totally reloaded.

Comment: @ChadCarbert, after reading the code you give,  there is something I can't understand. You just add an controller, and update it every time you refresh.  But I can't find where you use the query params in the url.

Comment: @ChristopherMilne, change my route.js now, and it is now like this:`this.route('ss', function() { this.route('xxx',{path:'/xxx/:id'}); });`; the model is like this:`model(params){this.store.query("yyyy",{id,params.id})}`, and the url is like `http://localhost:4200/#/ss/xxx/{id}`, but when I execute `this.refresh()`, the url changes to `http://localhost:4200/#/ss/xxx` as well.

Comment: @MonkeyKing The query param is used in the template, and you can set it in box above the template on the right. Here is a link to this use case: https://ember-twiddle.com/91b9ee17dc23579ff7c0379a4e5edc78?route=%2F%3Fpage%3Dhere-is-the-query-param I'm using a "page" query param which can be text or a number the example will still work. Does that answer your question?